# Update document in Meteor allow function

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have Messages collection and I removed insecure package. I want to insert new document into the collection. Is it possible to update current document before insertion?

This an example that does not work of course:

```
Messages.allow({
    insert: function(userID, doc) {

        if (userID == doc.userID) {
            // something like this
            doc = {
                email: Meteor.user().emails[0].address,
                message: doc.message,
                time: Date.now()
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see I am getting just `doc.message` from the client. But I would like to save also time and user's email into document. How could I do this in Meteor? Are methods the only option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this but you need to use a `deny` because a given `allow` isn't guaranteed to run. Give this a try:

```js
Posts.deny({insert: function(userId, doc) {
  if (userId === doc.userID) {
    _.defaults(doc, {
      email: Meteor.user().emails[0].address,
      time: Date.now()
    });
  }
  return false;
}});
```

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#how-can-i-alter-every-document-before-it-is-added-to-the-database) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 2):

It might be more preferable to use the collection-hooks package: https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks

It would allow you to insert a document both before or after another insert from another collection too.

e.g

```
Messages.before.insert(function (userId, doc) {
    doc.createdAt = Date.now();
    doc.xxx = false;
});
```